# Are deleted files sent to the recycle bin by Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox

Say I have drop box syncing to my Mac and PC. Next, I delete a file that is synced (either from one of the clients or the web interface). Obviously, this will cause the file to be removed automatically from the other clients.

My question is if it permanently deletes this file on that client, or simply moves it to the trash/recycling bin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it doesn't move it to the trash/recycle bin.

It stores it though under the `Dropbox/.dropbox.cash/` directory (on MacOS and Linux, and I guess something similar on Windows) for at least 3 days. So you can either browse this directory and find your deleted files or simply restore the deleted files from the Web UI and then files that are in the cache will be moved to the original directory.

Comment: On Windows, I think you'll find the relevant directory under your user's Application Data/Dropbox directory (on my system, for instance, it's C:\Documents and Settings\Michael Kohne\Application Data\Dropbox\cache)

Comment: @Michael check for hidden folders in your *My Dropbox* folder as well, because they've changed the cache location at one point and maybe this one is your old one!

Comment: No, I always keep hidden files displayed. On Windows, the Dropbox folks seem to be playing by the Windows rules and putting the cache folder in the user's AppData directory where it belongs.